# Removing navigation properties from POCO-classes in Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net, foreign-keys

I'm using generated POCO classes and Entity Framework.

In order to make the code less complex I'm trying to remove all navigation properties from the code while still keeping the Foreign Key constraints in the database (navigation properties do more harm than good for us).

If I remove them manually from the POCO-classes I get the following error

> The entity type UserEntity is not part of the model for the current context

If I try to remove them from the .edmx-file I get the following error:

> Error 3   Error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 479, 562:Foreign key constraint 'fk_StorageContracts_User1' from table StorageContract (OwnerUserID) to table User (ID):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side.

Is there any way to remove navigation properties from POCO-classes without removing the corresponding FK?

Comment: What problems do you have with navigational properties?

Comment: Using "generated POCO classes", are you working model-first? At what point do you get the "The entity type UserEntity is not part of the model for the current context" error?

Comment: @SteveWilkes: I am using this approach http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx (with EF 4.3). I get the error when I try to retrieve an entity from the db.

Comment: @Eranga: they add complexity without providing very much value (at least for us). For instance mocking your db becomes a lot more complex if you have to traverse all navigation properties at each save. They also often become a quite leaky abstraction, as they can easily become a performance bottleneck when you by mistake make tons of extra queries or very big joins.

Comment: @Yrlec Integration tests should be used with a real database for testing. You can disable lazy loading if you do not like it. You would lose rich domain modeling facilities and some querying benifits if you don't use navigational properties.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but, since there is still no answer, I thought I'd give it a try:

I am still working in EF 4.0, but, following the example to which you referred, you have an xxxModel.tt.  If you are willing to tweak that, you can find where it generates the Navigation Properties and change them to be simple auto-properties.  I had a similar project where I generated them like this:

```
public List<NavDataX> NavDataXs
{
    get; set;
}
```

Now, they are still there, but they are null until you explicitly set them.  Doing it this way, I did not mess with the EDMX and did not encounter the two errors you mentioned.

Comment: +1 to both the question and this answer which helped me track down my problem with EF 5.0.  

In my case, I have a .tt file in a separate project pointing to a global (large) .edmx file.  I tweaked it to suppress output for unwanted classes and navigation properties, but then couldn't figure out why the context wouldn't load my objects. 

I kept getting "The entity type [NAME] is not part of the model for the current context", for which most web search results suggest a connection problem, rather than a mapping problem.